# How to fix bug that null value row not return in oracle 11.2.0.1

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Not returning null rows in oracle  11.2.0.1.

My query is

```
select
  a."EMP_NO", a."DEPT_WING", a."TAKEN_PLACE_ID", a."TAKEN_PLACE_CODE",
  a."REQ_PLACE_ID", a."REQ_PLACE_CODE", a."TIFFEN_DATE", a."TIFFIN_REQ_DATE",
  a."TDATE", a."TIFFIN_MONTH", a."TIFFEN_TYPE", a."TIFFIN_ID",
  --(select EMPLOYEE_COST from TIFFEN_MASTER where TIFFIN_ID=a.TIFFIN_ID) as t,
  UPPER(NVL(APP,SWP))AS TIFFIN_SLOT
from
  (select
     nvl(v1.emp_no,v2.emp_no) emp_no, NVL(V1.DEPTWING,V2.DEPTWING)DEPT_WING,
     V1.PLACE_ID TAKEN_PLACE_ID, V1.PLACE_CODE TAKEN_PLACE_CODE,
     V2.PLACE_ID REQ_PLACE_ID, V2.PLACE_CODE REQ_PLACE_CODE, v1.tiffen_date,
     v2.tiffin_req_date, nvl(v1.tiffen_date,v2.tiffin_req_date) TDate,
     to_number(to_char(tiffin_req_date,'yyyymm'))tiffin_month,
     (case
       when trunc(tiffen_date) = trunc(tiffin_req_date) and V1.TIFFIN_SLOT=V2.TIFFIN_SLOT then 1
       when (((trunc(tiffin_REQ_DATE) <= trunc(sysdate-1)) or (trunc(tiffen_date) <= trunc(sysdate-1))) and (tiffin_id=8) and V1.TIFFIN_SLOT <> V2.TIFFIN_SLOT) then 2
       when (((trunc(tiffin_REQ_DATE) <= trunc(sysdate-1)) or (trunc(tiffen_date) <= trunc(sysdate-1))) and (tiffin_id is not null)and V1.TIFFIN_SLOT=V2.TIFFIN_SLOT) then 1
       when (((trunc(tiffin_REQ_DATE) <= trunc(sysdate-1)) or (trunc(tiffen_date) <= trunc(sysdate-1))) and (tiffin_id=7) or V1.TIFFIN_SLOT <> V2.TIFFIN_SLOT) then 1
       when ((trunc(tiffin_REQ_DATE) <= trunc(sysdate-1)) or (trunc(tiffen_date) <= trunc(sysdate-1)) and V1.TIFFIN_SLOT <> V2.TIFFIN_SLOT) then 2
       else 0
     end ) Tiffen_type, tiffin_id, V2.TIFFIN_SLOT APP, V1.TIFFIN_SLOT AS SWP
   from
     (select
        emp_no, trunc(tiffin_req_date) tiffin_req_date,
        NVL(L.PLACE_ID,1) PLACE_ID, PLACE_CODE, E.DEPTWING, TIFFIN_SLOT
      from
        Tiffin_Applied L, LUNCH_PLACES P, V_EMP_DETAILS E
      WHERE
        EMP_NO=ID_NO AND
        P.place_id = NVL(L.PLACE_ID,1)
      ORDER BY 2) v2
     FULL OUTER JOIN (select emp_no,trunc(tiffen_date) tiffen_date,1 PLACE_ID,PLACE_CODE,E.DEPTWING,l.tiffin_id,TIFFIN_SLOT from Tiffen L,LUNCH_PLACES P,V_EMP_DETAILS E WHERE EMP_NO=ID_NO and (actinact=1 or actinact is null) AND P.PLACE_ID = NVL(1,1)) v1 ON
       v2.EMP_NO=v1.EMP_NO AND
       v2.TIFFIN_SLOT=v1.TIFFIN_SLOT AND
       v2.TIFFIN_REQ_DATE=v1.TIFFEN_DATE
   order by nvl(tiffen_date,tiffin_req_date)) a
WHERE
  EMP_NO ='17RD021';
```

[image: please find the query result in the image. Row number 5 has some null values tiffin_place_codem tiffin_date]

If we uncomment 4th line in query then 5th row not coming in Query result in oracle 10.2.0.1. Why? Please help me. But in oracle 10.2.0.3 even 4th line uncomment, we will get this 4 th line in result.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: a minimal example of your query that demonstrates the problem (try to remove all the unnecessary parts and simplify it to only show the bits related to the error); also, include DDL and DML statements (as text, not images) for your tables and the test data that demonstrates the issue; the expected output (again as text, not images) for your test data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result in both the versions using `left join`.

```
SELECT
    A."EMP_NO",
    A."DEPT_WING",
    A."TAKEN_PLACE_ID",
    A."TAKEN_PLACE_CODE",
    A."REQ_PLACE_ID",
    A."REQ_PLACE_CODE",
    A."TIFFEN_DATE",
    A."TIFFIN_REQ_DATE",
    A."TDATE",
    A."TIFFIN_MONTH",
    A."TIFFEN_TYPE",
    A."TIFFIN_ID",
    TM.EMPLOYEE_COST   AS T, -- changed this
    UPPER(NVL(APP, SWP)) AS TIFFIN_SLOT
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            NVL(V1.EMP_NO, V2.EMP_NO) EMP_NO,
            NVL(V1.DEPTWING, V2.DEPTWING) DEPT_WING,
            V1.PLACE_ID      TAKEN_PLACE_ID,
            V1.PLACE_CODE    TAKEN_PLACE_CODE,
            V2.PLACE_ID      REQ_PLACE_ID,
            V2.PLACE_CODE    REQ_PLACE_CODE,
            V1.TIFFEN_DATE,
            V2.TIFFIN_REQ_DATE,
            NVL(V1.TIFFEN_DATE, V2.TIFFIN_REQ_DATE) TDATE,
            TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TIFFIN_REQ_DATE, 'yyyymm')) TIFFIN_MONTH,
            ( CASE
                WHEN TRUNC(TIFFEN_DATE) = TRUNC(TIFFIN_REQ_DATE)
                     AND V1.TIFFIN_SLOT = V2.TIFFIN_SLOT THEN 1
                WHEN ( ( ( TRUNC(TIFFIN_REQ_DATE) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) )
                         OR ( TRUNC(TIFFEN_DATE) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) ) )
                       AND ( TIFFIN_ID = 8 )
                       AND V1.TIFFIN_SLOT <> V2.TIFFIN_SLOT ) THEN 2
                WHEN ( ( ( TRUNC(TIFFIN_REQ_DATE) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) )
                         OR ( TRUNC(TIFFEN_DATE) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) ) )
                       AND ( TIFFIN_ID IS NOT NULL )
                       AND V1.TIFFIN_SLOT = V2.TIFFIN_SLOT ) THEN 1
                WHEN ( ( ( TRUNC(TIFFIN_REQ_DATE) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) )
                         OR ( TRUNC(TIFFEN_DATE) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) ) )
                       AND ( TIFFIN_ID = 7 )
                       OR V1.TIFFIN_SLOT <> V2.TIFFIN_SLOT ) THEN 1
                WHEN ( ( TRUNC(TIFFIN_REQ_DATE) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) )
                       OR ( TRUNC(TIFFEN_DATE) <= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1) )
                       AND V1.TIFFIN_SLOT <> V2.TIFFIN_SLOT ) THEN 2
                ELSE 0
            END ) TIFFEN_TYPE,
            TIFFIN_ID,
            V2.TIFFIN_SLOT   APP,
            V1.TIFFIN_SLOT   AS SWP
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    EMP_NO,
                    TRUNC(TIFFIN_REQ_DATE) TIFFIN_REQ_DATE,
                    NVL(L.PLACE_ID, 1) PLACE_ID,
                    PLACE_CODE,
                    E.DEPTWING,
                    TIFFIN_SLOT
                FROM
                    TIFFIN_APPLIED L,
                    LUNCH_PLACES P,
                    V_EMP_DETAILS E
                WHERE
                    EMP_NO = ID_NO
                    AND P.PLACE_ID = NVL(L.PLACE_ID, 1)
                ORDER BY
                    2
            ) V2
            FULL OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT
                    EMP_NO,
                    TRUNC(TIFFEN_DATE) TIFFEN_DATE,
                    1 PLACE_ID,
                    PLACE_CODE,
                    E.DEPTWING,
                    L.TIFFIN_ID,
                    TIFFIN_SLOT
                FROM
                    TIFFEN L,
                    LUNCH_PLACES P,
                    V_EMP_DETAILS E
                WHERE
                    EMP_NO = ID_NO
                    AND ( ACTINACT = 1
                          OR ACTINACT IS NULL )
                    AND P.PLACE_ID = NVL(1, 1)
            ) V1 ON V2.EMP_NO = V1.EMP_NO
                    AND V2.TIFFIN_SLOT = V1.TIFFIN_SLOT
                    AND V2.TIFFIN_REQ_DATE = V1.TIFFEN_DATE
        ORDER BY
            NVL(TIFFEN_DATE, TIFFIN_REQ_DATE)
    ) A
    LEFT JOIN TIFFEN_MASTER TM ON ( TM.TIFFEN_ID = A.TIFFIN_ID ) -- added this join 
    -- Please correct the names of the column according to your table's column name
WHERE
    EMP_NO = '17RD021';
```

I think the name of the columns is not proper. Please use correct names and you are good to go.

Cheers!!

Comment: @Tejesj SHOWING ERROR AT LEFT JOIN TIFFEN_MASTER TM ON (TM.TIFFEN_ID = A.TIFFEN_ID)  please check once.